# How to group properties together when serializing to JSON

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a flat object that I would like to group into sections in order to make parsing it easier. This is the basic idea of what my class currently looks like:

```
class Populations {
  public string US { get; set; }
  public string Canada { get; set; }

  public string Germany { get; set; }
  public string England { get; set; }
}
```

But this is what I want it to be serialized into when populated with data:

```
{
  "Populations": {
    "North America": {
      "US": "318 million",
      "Canada": "35 million" 
    },
    "Europe": {
      "Germany": "80 million",
      "England": "53 million"
    }
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is wrap my countries into continents without actually creating new continent classes. Is this possible with a tool like Json.Net or do I simply have to create a `NorthAmerica` class with two properties and then create a `Europe` class with two properties? Is it possible an annotation exists to allow me group together some of these properties?

Comment: `wrap my countries into continents` Where is the map function for this....

Comment: Use an array of classes `Country` having `Name`, `Population` and `Continent` properties.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in mechanism in Json.Net to do this grouping as you describe; however, you could make a custom `JsonConverter` to do it if that's what you really want.  Something like this might work:

```
class GroupAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public GroupAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

class GroupingConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = new JObject();
        Type type = value.GetType();
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in type.GetProperties())
        {
            JToken propVal = JToken.FromObject(pi.GetValue(value));
            GroupAttribute group = pi.GetCustomAttribute<GroupAttribute>();
            if (group != null)
            {
                JObject groupObj = (JObject)obj[group.Name];
                if (groupObj == null)
                {
                    groupObj = new JObject();
                    obj.Add(group.Name, groupObj);
                }
                groupObj.Add(pi.Name, propVal);
            }
            else
            {
                obj.Add(pi.Name, propVal);
            }
        }

        JObject wrapper = new JObject(new JProperty(type.Name, obj));
        wrapper.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // CanConvert is not called when a [JsonConverter] attribute is applied
        return false;
    }
}
```

You would then mark up your `Populations` class like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(GroupingConverter))]
class Populations 
{
    [Group("North America")]
    public string US { get; set; }
    [Group("North America")]
    public string Canada { get; set; }

    [Group("Europe")]
    public string Germany { get; set; }
    [Group("Europe")]
    public string England { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, serialize like this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(populations, Formatting.Indented);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EPiJue

Comment: Thank u for the solution, but can we custom this to return just a specific group ? 
For example
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(populations, Formatting.Indented,"Europe");
and it returns 
Group("Europe")]

Answer (score 1):

You could create classes `NorthAmerica` and `Europe`, or you could do something like:

```
class Continent{
    string Type { get; set; }
    ICollection<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

This would of course necessitate that all your countries have a common base class or interface.

Comment: Wouldn't this serialize into something slightly different than the json he wants? His json seems to imply that he wants NorthAmerica to have properties of US and Canada. The Continent class you propose would make them an array when serialized, right?

Comment: @JaredDrake It's different than the JSON, but he also said "this is what I'm trying to do".  Neither directly accomplishes his goal, but...

Comment: Ya, I understand what you mean. He's going to have to give on his JSON or making/modifying classes.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how your JSON doesn't have arrays, you're current classes make this json impossible to create unless you create another class with the exact structure you would want or Select it into a dynamic object.

If you must strictly abide by this JSON, I would encourage you to make a different population class that has a structure like

```
class Populations {
    public NorthAmerica NorthAmerica { get; set; }
    public Europe Europe { get; set; }
}

class NorthAmerica{
    public string US { get; set; }
    public string Canada { get; set; }
}

class Europe{
    public string Germany{ get; set; }
    public string England{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about the properties of `Populations` ?  `Germany` or `Europe`

Comment: @Eser Fixed it. Thanks!