# How to group properties together when serializing to JSON with JsonConverter<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, json.net, odata, ef-core-2.2

I will change my question all together leaving the initial question at the bottom.

I will try to explain what I'm trying to achieve without providing the underlying solution as I did before.

Time is not on my side unfortunately so please bear with me.

#### Here goes my question:

We use an old Oracle database which was modelled more than twenty years ago. It contain tables with hundred of columns and million of lines.

We need to expose some of those tables through an api, and as we have multiple use cases I thought it would be a good idea to use Odata so everyone can meet their requirements without have to create specific models for everyone.

I did not find a single solution using ODP.Net that would allow me to expose IQueryables without loading the entire tables (again, millions of lines). This is why I felt my only solution would be EF Core database first.

I was able to create a model based on the existing db model but what I’m trying to achieve is to split those huge table in multiple smaller models that would make more sense without losing odata capabilities.

My apologies if my initial question was misleading and if it did not provide the underlying problem.

Does anyone could help me do the same as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656880/how-to-group-properties-together-when-serializing-to-json) but with net8 and [JsonConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1?view=net-8.0) ?

The idea is to group properties using attributes on classes generated with ef core database first

Thanks !

EDIT:
Let's say I have a table 'Person' with the following properties:

- ID
- Name
- Address Line 1
- Address Line 2
- Address Line 3

And I'd like to regroup all the Address properties into a group named 'Address'

What would be the best solution to do so ?

Edit 2:

Currently I'm exposing an Odata controller which targets directly my dbcontext and my dbsets:

```
[MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
[HttpGet]
[ResponseCache(Duration = 30, VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "*" })]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[EnableQuery]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_context.Address), Formatting.Indented));
}
```

Comment: When trying to use the solution provided in the question I refer to, I have the following issue and can't find a solution so I'd rather go to JsonConverter: "The converter specified on 'xxx' does not derive from JsonConverter or have a public parameterless constructor"

Comment: Could it be that you're experiencing a conflict between `Newtonsoft` and `System.Text.Json`? Which one are you using?

Comment: Sidenote: "The idea is to group properties using attributes on classes generated with ef core database first". You are trying to use the same model for two different things. That is is typically a bad idea. Good practice is to use different models for different domains/problems and map between them.

Comment: @P.Magnusson I'm an idiot, that was the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Ralf How would you create two different models in a database first approach ? Can this be only done using fluent api or can I do that with data annotations ?

Comment: I've updated my question to provide more details on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: As you need a model to present something as Json it has presumably nothing todo with your database model (atleast technically) so has to be created independently. If you want to create both automatically you don't need it in the first place as they would be the same then.  If you want a json representation with a specific layout create a model representing that and then map between the model with the database representation and the one fitting for json.

Comment: @ElBarto that's not deserialization you're asking for completely new objects. The question you link to got the same answer. You didn't what *you* want either, because there's no obvious way that a name and some flat address lines can be grouped together

Comment: `generated with ef core database first` that has nothing to do either with JSON. What is the real question? Are you trying to load JSON data using EF Core 7 or 8? Have you checked the [JSON Columns supprot](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef7-release-candidate-2/)?

Comment: I'm exposing an api through Odata, hence I'm targetting the ef model directly at the moment. I don't have a better solution at the moment. I would be glad if you could point me in the correct direction. I will update my question with more details.

Comment: OData doesn't need that at all. The code you posted isn't OData code either, it's just a bug. It serializes the same object *twice* resulting in a flat string result

Comment: The database model is incorrect, was designed years ago and won't change. On the other hand I want to expose it through an api using odata. What I'm trying to do, clearly not correctly is to change the model which is exposed on the response of the api without having to change the database model. I'd need to group different properties together.

Comment: If you want to allow querying on a DbSet you should return an IQueryable, not a single object. Your code should change to `public IQueryable<Address> Get()=>_context.Address.AsQueryable();`. If you want to reshape the data you'll have to do that in the action itself

Comment: @ElBarto `change the model which is exposed on the response` create new classes then, and perform any conversions in the action. ASP.NET Core OData (and the previous versions) will apply the client's select, filter and other operators on the IQueryable returned by the action

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Would you mind posting a simple example on how to "change the model wich is exposed on the response" ? Because that's a huge database, I'd like not to rewrite the whole fluent api to match my need (if there is a simpler solution)

Comment: `.Select(original=>new NewClass(....))`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry, that's not clear. What if the client did not chose the group Address in his request but only the Id ?

Comment: That's ASP.NET Core OData's job, not the action's. If the client sends a `$select` parameter, ASP.NET Core OData will add the `.Select(x=>new {x.SelectField1, x.SelectField2,...})` call needed to retrieve just those fields

Comment: I don't know if I don't understand or I'm not clear enough. In my example the database exposes three properties. Addres1, Address2 and Address3. I'd like to expose all the three of them as a single property named Address which would expose the three values.

Comment: If the mapping is so complex it can't be translated to SQL, or if you just want to use a different query, you can create an action that accepts an `ODataQueryOptions<Address> options` parameter and either apply the parameters to another IQueryable with `ODataQueryOptions.Apply`, or inspect the actual select, filter, select etc options

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos would you be so kind to post an answer with a simple example that I'd glady mark as an answer ?

Comment: @ElBarto `if I don't understand or I'm not clear enough` it's seems you just started working with OData. I suggest going through the [ASP.NET Core OData Getting Started tutorial with static data ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/getting-started) and the one [using EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/tutorials/basic-crud?tabs=net60%2Cvisual-studio-2022%2Cvisual-studio%2Cvs2022) instead of trying to just write code. OData is quirky and *NOT* tied to EF at all. ASP.NET Core maps requests to controllers that in turn use EF

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Based on my edit, do you have more information to give me ? I have a hard time finding the information I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering I managed to do what I needed exposing Views on top of my tables which helped me redifine the functional schema.

I then used Fluent Api to target the views instead of the tables.

Comment: You now gave an answer to your own question, which was in fact not an answer but an elaboration. Please edit your original post

Comment: @RaimondKuipers I don't get what's wrong with providing an answer to my problem. It is the best solution I found to resolve the scenario I was facing. What should I have done differently ?